# Show multiple input textbox by another value in vCenter Orchestrator

Tags: vmware, orchestration, vcenter

I'm working for an automation job about virtual machine deploying with use vRealize Orchestrator.

I want IP addresses from user by virual machine number. So if the requester want 3 virtual machines, my workflow must take IP addresses for 3 virtual machines. if the requester want 2, then my workflow must take addresses for 2 virtual machine.

Example Screenshots:

[Workflow ask IP Address for 1 VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLAG3.png)

[Workflow ask IP Address for 2 VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx0Wp.png)

I can hide/show input at presentation but I don't want it because it damages the flexibility of workflow. It maybe works for 4-5 VM but I can need more. How can I do this for more VMs?

Note: I can take the IP addresses as an array but in this option the length of array must be equal to VM number.

Answer (score 0):

You can request all the IPs in a single string separated by comas then parse them later on. For example: 1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3 etc. That is probably the easiest method.

Method 2:

1. One separate user interaction to request the number of VMs. Let's say vmCount
2. Another separate user interaction to request exactly 1 IP address string. Let's say ipAddr
3. Scriptable task after this user interaction that does array.push(ipAddr)
4. Loop over this user interaction and scriptable task as many times as vmCount

At the end you will have an array that contains as many IPs as vmCount.

[image: example]

Comment: thanks but i want to another thing. sorry my english. if the requester requests 3 vm he/she must enter 3 ip not 2 or 4. my problem is this.